# What should I do to use or import those consts in the Drawerr.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using Next.js. In `Nav.js` I have these `const`s:

```
export default function NestedList() {
  const [value,setValue]=React.useState();
  const theme=useTheme();
  const isMatch=useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('lg'));
  const [on, seton] = useState(false);
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [bea, setBea] = useState([]);
  const [home, setHome] = useState([]);
  const [aaa, setaaa] = useState(0); 
  const [bbb, setbbb] = useState(0); 
  const [ccc, setccc] = useState(0);
  //I did not show the return function.
}
```

and in `Drawerr.js` I have this code:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import {Drawer, IconButton, List, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText,Box} from "@mui/material";
import MenuRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuRounded";
import Image from 'next/image';
import { height } from '@mui/system';
import Nav from './Nav';

const Drawerr = ({linkArray}) => {
   const [open, setopen] = useState(false)
  return (
     <>
        <Drawer  PaperProps={{sx:{backgroundColor:'#035445'}}} open={open} onClose={()=> setopen(false)}>
            <List>
               <Box component="img" src="/dlogo.svg" sx={{ mt:-1, height:125,width:250}}/>

               {linkArray.map((link,index)=>(
                  <ListItemButton divider key={index} onClick={()=>setopen(false)}   >
                     <ListItemIcon >
                        <ListItemText  sx={{ color:"#00ffd0" }} onClick={()=>{

                              if(index==1 ){setaaa(aaa+30),setbbb(bbb==0),setccc(ccc==0)}
                              if(index==4 ){setaaa(aaa==0),setccc(ccc==0),setbbb(bbb+30)}
                              if(index==0 ){setaaa(aaa==0),setbbb(bbb==0),setccc(ccc+30)}



                        }}>
                           {link}
                        </ListItemText>
                     </ListItemIcon>
                  </ListItemButton>

               ))}

            </List>

        </Drawer>
        <IconButton  onClick={()=>setopen(!open)} sx={{marginLeft:"auto" ,color:"#00a859"}}>
            
            <MenuRoundedIcon/>
        </IconButton>
     </>
  )
}

export default Drawerr
```

So I can't use those `const`s In `Drawerr.js` and I get this error:

> ReferenceError: setaaa is not defined

What should I do to use those `const`s in Drawerr.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing

```
import Nav from './Nav';
```

here Nav is a function and not a object, now as per your code i can see you are trying impement custom hook? if i m right, you can create custom hook in react like this

```
export default function useNestedList() {
 const [value,setValue]=React.useState();
 const theme=useTheme();
 const isMatch=useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('lg'));
 const [on, seton] = useState(false);
 const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
 const [bea, setBea] = useState([]);
 const [home, setHome] = useState([]);
 const [aaa, setaaa] = useState(0); 
 const [bbb, setbbb] = useState(0); 
 const [ccc, setccc] = useState(0);
 //I did not show the return function.
 return {
    setaaa:setaaa,
    setbbb:setbbb,
    setccc:setccc,
    aaa:aaa,
    bbb:bbb,
    ccc:ccc
 }
}
```

and after that you can use this hook as this way in drawer.js

```
 import {useState} from 'react'
 import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
 import {Drawer, IconButton, List, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon,ListItemText,Box} from "@mui/material";
 import MenuRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuRounded";
 import Image from 'next/image';
 import { height } from '@mui/system';
 import useNestedList from './Nav';

 const Drawerr = ({linkArray}) => {
  const [open, setopen] = useState(false)
  const { setaaa,setbbb,setccc,aaa,bbb,ccc} =useNestedList()
  return (
 <>
    <Drawer  PaperProps={{sx:{backgroundColor:'#035445'}}} open={open} onClose={()=> setopen(false)}>
        <List>
           <Box component="img" src="/dlogo.svg" sx={{ mt:-1, height:125,width:250}}/>

           {linkArray.map((link,index)=>(
              <ListItemButton divider key={index} onClick={()=>setopen(false)}   >
                 <ListItemIcon >
                    <ListItemText  sx={{ color:"#00ffd0" }} onClick={()=>{

                          if(index==1 ){setaaa(aaa+30),setbbb(bbb==0),setccc(ccc==0)}
                          if(index==4 ){setaaa(aaa==0),setccc(ccc==0),setbbb(bbb+30)}
                          if(index==0 ){setaaa(aaa==0),setbbb(bbb==0),setccc(ccc+30)}



                    }}>
                       {link}
                    </ListItemText>
                 </ListItemIcon>
              </ListItemButton>

           ))}

        </List>

    </Drawer>
    <IconButton  onClick={()=>setopen(!open)} sx={{marginLeft:"auto" ,color:"#00a859"}}>
        
        <MenuRoundedIcon/>
    </IconButton>
 </>
   )}

 export default Drawerr
```

Hope this will help!